# Flat Catalog Product - getSku do not work

Tags: magento-1.9, flat-catalog, sku

If i activate Flat Catalog Product, than Magento do not view sku on Product and category page with this code:

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getSku()); ?>
```

Comment: did you reindex product flat data?

Comment: yes, clear all cache + reindex, repeatedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the SKU attribute is not loaded. It should be enough to edit the `sku` attribute under `Catalog - Attributes - Manage Attributes`. If you want to use it on the product page, set "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" to "Yes". If you want to use it on the category page, set "Used in Product Listing" to "Yes".